# Linking directly to Wagtail modeladmin views

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm successfully using Wagtail's `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin` to make a regular Django model editable from the Wagtail admin. I'd like to hyperlink to the modeladmin "create" and "edit" views from my template. What is the URL "name" I can use to reference these views? There appears to be no `urls` module in `wagtail.contrib.admin` and no documentation on this.

Here's my `directory` app's `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Organisation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos', blank=True)
    ...
```

And my project's `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    ...
    url(r'^directory/', include('directory.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The URL name will be of the following form, where `[action]` is one of `index`, `create`, `edit`, `delete`, `inspect` or `choose_parent`:

```
[app_label]_[model_name]_modeladmin_[action]
```

For example:

- `{% url 'directory_organisation_modeladmin_index' %}`
- `{% url 'directory_organisation_modeladmin_create' %}`
- `{% url 'directory_organisation_modeladmin_edit' instance_pk=37 %}`
- `{% url 'directory_organisation_modeladmin_delete' instance_pk=37 %}`
- `{% url 'directory_organisation_modeladmin_inspect' instance_pk=37 %}`
- `{% url 'directory_organisation_modeladmin_choose_parent' %}`

Since the URLConf provided doesn't contain a namespace argement to `include()`, no namespace is required.

Similar to Django's built-in Admin, Wagtail generates these URLs dynamically in the [`ModelAdmin.get_admin_urls_for_registration()`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v1.10.1/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py#L60) with some helpers like [`AdminURLHelper.get_action_url_name()`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v1.10.1/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/helpers/url.py#L29).